# I can't see any changes in Magento homepages

Tags: magento-1.9, css, html, phtml

I'm trying to add a picture into front page ( home page ) in my eCommerce website. I'm adding the codes on the server files ( home.phtml) and when I save it nothing is happenening. even tho I've the same website installed in another server and same copy and I do same changes and it does work on the other server! I spent all day today looking for a solution and it's getting me to the point of having a heart attack :) any advice of what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You should delete all folders from var\cache because some time refreshing cache still leave the footprints of layout files.

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple. Go to system -> cache management and click flush magento cache. You will need to do that every time after you change something.